# Fan control for newer Thinkpad Lenovo (T460 series and above)

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, thinkpad, fancontrol

If I install Ubuntu 16.04 on a T460 thinkpad, can I control the fan using a custom fan control script/utility?

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the fan is adjusted by the bios automatically based on the temperatures in your Thinkpad. But if you really want to control the fan, there is a old program called [ThinkPad-Fan-Control](https://github.com/Stanko/ThinkPad-Fan-Control)

BUT, before you do anything, please read the README. This program is quite old and discontinued.

I also recommend you read this article on the thinkwiki: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed

Comment: While it seems to be supported for older thinkpad models, i haven't come across any post suggesting that they work for the newer thinkpad models (T460, T470). Before buying the laptop, I want to ensure that newer thinkpad allows user to control the fan (Dell Xps, for example, doesn't seem to do this).

Comment: @cosmo17 it looks to me like many newer laptops/desktops from lenove have a poor suport for controlling the fan speeds,on my desktop ideacentre 510s the fan spins too slow and the only time there is a hint of speedcontroll is during a hard reboot and there is no option in bios to change fanspeed.